# How can append td in same row in table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.zk_btn').click(function(e) {
    var pass_symbol= $('#' + lastid).val();
    var split_id = lastid.split("_");
    var nextindex = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;

    $.ajax({
      url:"record_count_3.php?pass_symbol=" + pass_symbol,
      method:"POST",
      success:function(data)
        {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        var txt = '';

        if(json.length > 0){
          for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
            txt = "<td>"+json[i].openrate+"</td><td>"+json[i].highrate+"</td><td>"+json[i].lowrate+"</td><td>"+json[i].closerate+"</td>";
                                                
            $("#example > tbody > tr").append(txt);
          }
          $('#example > tbody').append('<tr class="txt_ '+  nextindex +'"><td><input type="text" id="txt_'+ nextindex +'" name="symbol"  class="txtfield"  /></td></tr> </tbody>');
        }   
        $('.content').html(data);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

I have a problem iam fetching data from ajax call and move in json varibale.when write symbol in input box and fetching records and display in 1st td,and append in new row. and  another insert symbol and click submit button fetching the record and display in second td but problem  second record display in first  row and second  row just like screen shot. mcb records display in 2nd row not in 1st row. please suggest my mistake

```html
  <table id='example' border='1' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' style='width:900px;' >
    <thead>
      <th> Marksymbol</th>
      <th class='namecol '> Openrate</th>
      <th class='namecol'> Highrate</th>
      <th class='namecol'> Lowrate</th>
      <th class='namecol'> Closerate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class ='txt_1'>
      <td > <input type='text' name="symbol" id='txt_1'  class='txtfield'/>
      </td>
    </tr>
                                            
</table>

<input type="button" id= "btnclick" class="zk_btn zk_btn_submit" name="submit1" value="SUBMIT"/>
```

Comment: Replace `$("#example > tbody > tr").append(txt);` with `$("#example > tbody").append("<tr>" + txt + "</tr>");` (there are better ways to do this though)

Comment: next time, take the time to properly indent your code (it was unreadable) and I wouldn't have spent mine doing it rather than thinking about an answer. maybe someone else will want to think about it, because it completely demotivated me

Comment: Here's some code demonstrating how to prevent HTML string composition and make things a bit more readable and concise: https://jsfiddle.net/xt6kf8a7/

Comment: not working that code $("#example > tbody").append("<tr>" + txt + "</tr>")  in next row.i want data display in same row

Answer (score 0):

It's working now

```
$('#example tr:last').closest('tr').append(txt);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).